# Visual Studio Online build times are increasing dramatically

Tags: build, continuous-integration, azure-devops

On my development machine (Dell XPS 8700), I can build my solution in 1 minute. Using VSO to build it takes much longer. Also, my build times over the past 10 days are increasing dramatically, even though I've only made minor changes to the source.

Here are the last 4 build times for the line in the log that says "Run MSBuild":

- 7:11
- 10:56
- 14:32
- 22:33

Does anybody know why this is happening?

With only 60 minutes of included build time per month, this is an issue for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were having some issues with the build service a couple of weeks ago - when you posted the question. Is this problem still occurring?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm no longer having that problem. It must have been temporary, as you said. It's a bit unfair that if the build service is having problems such that builds are taking much longer, then I get charged for the extra minutes out of my allowance!

Comment: Please contact support and request a credit for the extra minutes. We're happy to make it right - you shouldn't pay for a problem on our side. Click the Visual Studio Online tile under "Answer wasn’t there? Talk to us” on http://www.visualstudio.com/support-overview-vs.